# Creating new jupyter notebook: 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have just installed Python 3.9.1 and pip 21.0.1, but I can't make Jupyter Notebook to work. I can open it, but I can't create a new Python 3 Notebook (500: Internal Server Error).
I have tried different solutions that were suggested on stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work. Could someone point me in the right direction of what's going wrong here?

```
[E 12:31:46.068 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /notebooks/Untitled1.ipynb?kernel_name=python3 (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/notebooks/Untitled1.ipynb?kernel_name=python3', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1704, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 775, in run
        yielded = self.gen.send(value)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebook/handlers.py", line 95, in get
        self.write(self.render_template('notebook.html',
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 516, in render_template
        return template.render(**ns)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
        self.environment.handle_exception()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
        reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/notebook.html", line 1, in top-level template code
        {% extends "page.html" %}
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/page.html", line 154, in top-level template code
        {% block header %}
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/notebook.html", line 115, in block "header"
        {% for exporter in get_frontend_exporters() %}
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebook/handlers.py", line 40, in get_frontend_exporters
        for name in get_export_names():
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 141, in get_export_names
        e = get_exporter(exporter_name)(config=config)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 102, in get_exporter
        if getattr(exporter(config=config), 'enabled', True):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 325, in __init__
        super().__init__(config=config, **kw)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 114, in __init__
        self._init_preprocessors()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 491, in _init_preprocessors
        conf = self._get_conf()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 509, in _get_conf
        if conf_path.exists():
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1407, in exists
        self.stat()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1221, in stat
        return self._accessor.stat(self)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/conf.json'
[E 12:31:46.091 NotebookApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"87\", \" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"87\"",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
      "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/tree",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|85632aaa|64c82af63fd0966e14c03d95ba64a8a9|1612261353; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1612265499|23:username-localhost-8888|44:OTNlN2QxZGM3NTNiNDQwMDg5NmNkNjhlNmU4ODA4YTQ=|0d8e7a82c04f0bd92a53e19f819e7204c81853c25412c8bbb8f60e5e95ebccf2\""
    }
[E 12:31:46.091 NotebookApp] 500 GET /notebooks/Untitled1.ipynb?kernel_name=python3 (::1) 262.630000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Check https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1430. Seems like you've got the permissions wrong to the folder.

Answer (score 2):

use this command in conda promt:

```
conda install nbconvert=5.4.1
```

and downgrade torrnado to version 5

if the problem is not gone just update jupyter

```
conda update jupyter
```

it works for me

Comment: @CrApHeR: Why do you say that? [Please review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).